# overwriting adminhtml block from another extension doesn't work

Tags: blocks, overrides

I'm trying to find a solution since a couple hours now. Unfortunately without any luck, so I need to ask you for help.

I'm trying to add a download button to a grid which will be provided by an extension. 
If I'm customize the concerning file in Block/Adminhtml/O directly the button shows up ([Add a button to admin grid](http://magentomods.wordpress.com/2012/10/04/how-to-add-a-custom-button-to-an-admin-page-magento-ee-1-12-0-2/)). But I don't want to customize the extension - I want to overwrite the concerning block. And this is where I got stuck. Nothing happens, it seems there is an issue somewhere but I can't find it.

Here is my code

My confix.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
   <modules>
       <Foo_Quotedownload>
           <version>0.1.0</version>
       </Foo_Quotedownload>
   </modules>
   <global>
      <blocks>
          <rewrite>
  <adminhtml_qquoteadv>Foo_Quotedownload_Block_Adminhtml_Qquoteadv</adminhtml_qquoteadv>
            </rewrite>
      </blocks>
   </global>
</config>
```

My app/etc/modules/Foo_Quotedownload.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Quotedownload>
            <active>true</active>
            <codePool>local</codePool>
            <depends>
                <Ophirah_Qquoteadv/>
            </depends>
        </Foo_Quotedownload>
    </modules>   
</config>
```

The original config.xml from the module (only interesting part)

```
<blocks>
<qquoteadv>
    <class>Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block</class>
</qquoteadv>
<checkout>
    <rewrite>
        <onepage_shipping_method_available>Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block_Checkout_Onepage_Shipping_Method_Available</onepage_shipping_method_available>
    </rewrite>
</checkout>
</blocks>
```

The original concerning Block

```
<?php
class Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block_Adminhtml_Qquoteadv extends    
Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
```

My block which lives in Foo/Quotedownload/Block/Adminhtml/Qquoteadv.php

```
<?php
class Foo_Quotedownload_Block_Adminhtml_Qquoteadv extends   
Ophirah_Qquoteadv_Block_Adminhtml_Qquoteadv {

public function __construct()
{
  echo "works";
  die;  
    $this->_controller = 'adminhtml_qquoteadv';
    $this->_blockGroup = 'qquoteadv';
    $this->_headerText = Mage::helper('qquoteadv')->__('Quotations');
    $this->_addButtonLabel = Mage::helper('sales')->__('Create Neeeew Quote');

           ///////CUSTOM code for new button:
   $data = array(
           'label' =>  'Download Quotes',
           'onclick'   => "setLocation('".$this->getUrl('qquoteadv/adminhtml_qquoteadv/download')."')"
           );
   ///////The URL I am using is a custom module that I set up earlier, Magento parses it to <MySite.com/shop/index.php/downloadtomas>, which then runs the script I have in the IndexController.php file
   Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container::addButton('download_to_mas', $data, 0, 100,  'header', 'header');
   ///////End CUSTOM code


    parent::__construct();
}
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you are missing the block node for the original extension you are rewriting in your config.xml. Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Foo_Quotedownload>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Foo_Quotedownload>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <qquoteadv>
                <rewrite>
                    <adminhtml_qquoteadv>Foo_Quotedownload_Block_Adminhtml_Qquoteadv</adminhtml_qquoteadv>
                </rewrite>
            </qquoteadv>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You were right, now it works. You really helped me a lot! Have a nice weekend.