# I want to override these files in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

```
1. app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php

2. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml

3. app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/view/options.phtml

4.app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/type/select.phtml
```

How to achieve this in module ?

Answer (score 2):

1.app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Edit/Tab/Options/Option.php

```
 <global>
    <blocks>
       <adminhtml>
          <rewrite>
            <catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option</catalog_product_edit_tab_options_option>
          </rewrite>
      </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
   </global>
```

2.app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit/options/option.phtml

```
class Spacename_Modulename_Block_Adminhtml_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Option  extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options
    {
        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setTemplate('test/yours.phtml'); // add you phtml file here
        }
    }
```

same goes for **point 4**. 
override Block

`Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Edit_Tab_Options_Type_Select`

and set template in

```
__construct
```

**3 point** [Changing the product custom option renderer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52631/changing-the-product-custom-option-renderer)

Comment: 3 Point.  Can I override options.phtml  through local.xml without creating new block.

Comment: @Pankaj if you are creating theme ten copy file in your theme and edit their.

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite a block follow this link: [overwriting adminhtml block from another extension doesn't work](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/29181/overwriting-adminhtml-block-from-another-extension-doesnt-work)

To override an adminhtml template follow this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14448983/magento-override-adminhtml-template-file